# Why is jQuery accessible from the console when loading it from within a custom element's scope?

Tags: javascript, polymer

I am loding jQuery within my polymer element as such:

```
<polymer-element attributes="_id assetClass bgColorClass isAuthor tags" name="x-actions-panel">
  <template>
     ...
  </template>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../vendor/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    Polymer("custom-el", {
      ...
    })
</polymer-element>
```

After loading jQuery as such, I am able to access it (`$`) from the console. How is that possible? Shouldn't a polymer component include the scripts in the shadow DOM? Does it load the scripts into the `ownerDocument` instead? If it does indeed load these into the `ownerDocument` is there a way of preventing it from doing so and keep the scripts in the shadowDOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Shadow Dom does have a [boundary](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/shadow/#shadow-trees). For instance css styles included in the shadow Root do not apply to the parent document.

However it does not get its own execution context(execution environment, whatever may be the correct term), like iframes do. Thus `<scripts></script>'s`, even though included in a shadow dom tree, are executed in the same context as the rest of the window.

And since jQuery and other libraries assign a global objects for the library ie:

```
window.jQuery = window.$ = ...
```

it is available everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Script tags in polymer-element are not "scoped", they are just loaded to the document. Only the stuff within the `template` tag are considered shadow DOM. In your example, the script tag is NOT in part of the shadow DOM.

If you do place the script tag in the shadow DOM, then JQuery would not be loaded until you create an instance of the `custom-el` - that's probably not what you want either.

To let scripts be in a "private scope", take a look at [Adding private or static variables](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/polymer.html). Basically, it is just wrapping your script in an anonymous function that runs immediately. More about [immediately invoked function expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/),

However, it only works with scripts you write, not external libraries like JQuery.